# The package willvincent/laravel-rateable failed to install on laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I'm trying to install willvincent/laravel-rateable package on laravel 8 but it requires:

> illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0

How do I solve this issue in order to use the rateable package?

```
- willvincent/laravel-rateable[2.2.0, ..., 2.2.1] require illuminate/support ^6.0|^7.0 -> found illuminate/support[v6.0.0, ..., 6.x-dev, v7.0.0, ..., 7.x-dev] but it conflicts with another require.
- Root composer.json requires willvincent/laravel-rateable ^2.2 -> satisfiable by willvincent/laravel-rateable[2.2.0, 2.2.1].
```

Comment: it would appear it does not support laravel 8 yet

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at https://packagist.org/packages/willvincent/laravel-rateable: this package is not compatibel with Laravel 8. There's already an issue posted at https://github.com/willvincent/laravel-rateable/issues/50, and a pull request at https://github.com/willvincent/laravel-rateable/pull/49/files.

You need to wait until the maintainer makes the package compatible - but through testing the pull request in your own application, you could provide feedback to the maintainer. That could speed up the process

Comment: I hope there is another solution I can opt to implement a rating feature in my Laravel 8 project.If so please let me know about it, thanks in advance.

Comment: Which other solution are you looking for? Is there anything not working with the given approach: test the pull request, let the maintainer know, speed up the merge and release process?

Comment: Have you even tried to contact the maintainer on your own? That's (most likely) the only person that can help you to make the package compatible

Comment: Appreciate your effort in answering my question. I will try the approach or contact the maintainer. Cheers.